# drag and drop sharepoint 2007

Tags: 2007, drag-and-drop

When I go to upload a document in my environment I get the normal browse to upload the document. Yet when someone else does it they get the drag and drop functionality.
It's not a webpart but wandering how I can get this on mine? is it a change in the browser settings or something?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the drag and drop functionality was available in SharePoint 2007. It could the `open with windows explorer` mode. Which opens the document library in explorer mode and then you can drag and drop items. You can find this option at `Actions -> Open with Windows Explorer`.

Comment: it does work, as I have seen it being used, its there is a link to add multiple files and when you click on that you can drag and drop. however you have to use IE10 and below